# Auto Login to User from Site to Disqus

Tags: single-sign-on, disqus

I added the Disqus to my website and making use of the script

SSO configuration is like this:

Name: example
Slug: example

no call back url is set at my end.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

/* * * CONFIGURATION VARIABLES * * */

var disqus_shortname = 'myexample';

var disqus_identifier = 'http://www.example.com/Welcome...

var disqus_title = 'My Example';

var disqus_url = 'http://www.example.com/Welcome...

var remote_auth_s3 = "<%=Payload%>";//Its generate by server side code

var api_key = "Public Api Key Is here";

/* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */

(function () {

var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;

dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';

(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);

})();

</script>
```

I am just using the above script and passing the values.
Will this script auto login my website users to Disqus or I have to do other extra efforts.

Thanks Dalvir

Answer (score 1):

My issue fixed after making use of variable like this

```
 var disqus_config = function () {
        // The generated payload which authenticates users with Disqus
        this.page.remote_auth_s3 = "<%=Payload%>";
        this.page.api_key = "<%=Key%>";

    };
```